# Select all integers that are not already in table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, gaps-and-islands, generate-series

I have some ids in a table, but there are gaps in between. I want to select these gaps.
For example, the integer numbers in my table are:

```
1
2
5
9
15
```

And I want to select:

```
3
4
6
7
8
10
11
12
13
14
```

My version of PostgreSQL is 9.1.1, so I cannot use int4range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`generate_series()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) and `LEFT JOIN` to the table:

```
SELECT g.nr
FROM   generate_series(1,15) g(nr)
LEFT   JOIN tbl USING (nr)
WHERE  tbl.nr IS NULL;
```

Replace all occurrences of `nr` with your actual column name.
Or use one of the other basic techniques:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

To determine the range dynamically:

```
SELECT g.nr
FROM  (SELECT generate_series(min(nr), max(nr)) AS nr FROM tbl) g
LEFT   JOIN tbl USING (nr)
WHERE  tbl.nr IS NULL;
```

Comment: You probably want to use `(select max(nr) from tbl)` rather than hardcoding the upper limit.

Comment: Thanks, generate_series() was missing :)

Comment: I have problem with left join. I replaced all tbls with my table name and nr in second row with column I have. When I run query I get this error:
ERROR:  column "nr" specified in USING clause does not exist in right table

Comment: @thecoparyew: Use the same name as your column name. Replace all instances of `nr` in my answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I just did that. But now query takes about 400s and still running. Table has about 2mio rows, and will just increase. So is there any chance to speed up this query?

Comment: @thecoparyew: You did not mention millions of rows in the question - where all basic information should be. The query is as simple and fast as it gets. 400 seconds seems excessive. Writing a table should be a matter of a few seconds at most. You are not, by any chance, loading 2 Mio. rows into your client (which would be pretty useless). I am off to bed now, good luck

Answer (score 2):

```
with t (id) as (
values (1), (2), (5), (9), (15)
)
select * from generate_series((select min(id) from t), (select max(id) from t)) as g(id)
where g.id not in (select id from t)
```