# How to get the number of users grouped by the number of comments they've made?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by

I'd like to get the count of users grouped by the number of comments they've made.

```
[User]: ID
[Comment]: ID, UserID
```

So if `user A has made 1 comment, user B has made 1 comment and user C has made 2 comments`, then the output would be:

```
0 comments => 0 users
1 comment  => 2 users (A+B)
2 comments => 1 user  (C)
```

How would you query this?

Comment: You are expected to provide the relevant table layout with the question, and what you have tried (even if it's not working). You have been around for long enough and should know the basics.

Comment: Hi Erwin! Actually, I wasn't aware of that rule, so glad you made the comment. I assumed the one-to-many association is so elementary and standard, that defining table layouts wouldn't be necessary. Anyhow, thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: There are many subtle variants. NOT NULL, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY constraints, data types, cardinalities, width of the row, indexes, frequencies of values, ... They all matter for the best solution. It's best to provide the (relevant parts of) your actual table layouts you get in psql with `\d tbl`. Better yet, provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) in an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/53c1c/3) (random example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on your specific database structure, but let's say you have a users table and a comments table:

```
users table:
id: serial
name: text

comments table:
id: serial
user_id: integer (foreign key to the users table)
comment: text
```

You can count the number of comments each user has made with this query:

```
  SELECT users.id, users.name, count(comments.id) as comment_cnt
    FROM users LEFT JOIN
         comments ON users.id = comments.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.name
```

You can then use the results of this query in a nested query to count the number of users for each number of comments:

```
  SELECT comment_cnt, count(*) FROM
  (SELECT users.id, users.name, count(comments.id) as comment_cnt
    FROM users LEFT JOIN
         comments ON users.id = comments.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.name) AS comment_cnts
GROUP BY comment_cnt;
```

I don't know of any elegant way to fill the gaps where there are zero users for a given number of comments, but a temporary table and another level of nesting works:

```
CREATE TABLE wholenumbers (num integer);

INSERT INTO wholenumbers VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);

   SELECT num as comment_cnt, COALESCE(user_cnt,0) as user_cnt
     FROM wholenumbers
LEFT JOIN (SELECT comment_cnt, count(*) AS user_cnt
             FROM (  SELECT users.id, users.name, count(comments.id) AS comment_cnt
                       FROM users LEFT JOIN comments ON users.id = comments.user_id
                   GROUP BY users.id, users.name) AS comment_cnts
         GROUP BY comment_cnt) AS user_cnts ON wholenumbers.num = user_cnts.comment_cnt
ORDER BY num;
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Small additional request: how would you go about filling the count gaps where there are no users for certain amount of comments (ie. `0 => 20 users, 1 => 0 users [we want this], 2 => 5 users`)?

Comment: I don't know of any elegant way to do that.  You could manually create a temporary table with a single integer column and n rows, each with one whole number in it 1, 2, 3, 4 ... however many you like.  You can then add another level of nesting.  I'll add the revised query to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter. I didn't know about that.  Does your solution show the number of users who have 0 comments?

Comment: @ClaytonC: Good point, thanks. Now it does. That makes more sense than starting with the smallest count.

Comment: Thanks again @ErwinBrandstetter. Looks like you also need to change the WITH query to reference the users table, otherwise there is no way to know how many users there are without any comments.  As it stands, your solution does not reference the users table at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59869/discussion-between-claytonc-and-erwin-brandstetter).

Comment: @ClaytonC: Considerably faster this way. But you are right, that count for users with 0 comments was missing, too. I added a bit to my answer to address that.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the table layout [@ClaytonC provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25467210/939860):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT msg_ct, count(*) AS users
   FROM  (
      SELECT count(*) AS msg_ct
      FROM   comments 
      GROUP  BY user_id
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT msg_ct, COALESCE(users, 0) AS users
FROM   generate_series(0, (SELECT max(msg_ct) FROM cte)) msg_ct
LEFT   JOIN cte USING (msg_ct)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

#### Major points

- First, count comments per user (`msg_ct`). As long as referential integrity is enforced by a foreign key, you do *not* need to join to the `users` table at all to aggregate comments per user. Just count rows in `comments`.
  Next, count users per message count (`users`).
- I am doing this in a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), because I use the derived table twice in the final query.
  First for [**`generate_series()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generate-series) to generate all counts from min to max **dynamically**, including gaps.
  Then for the table to `LEFT JOIN` to and get the final result.
- The count starts with 0 (after my update). If you want to have it start with the smallest actual `msg_ct`, consider the first draft of my answer in the edit history.
- Closely related answer explaining the basics:

  - [Select all integers that are not already in table in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441353/select-all-integers-that-are-not-already-in-table-in-postgres/25441483#25441483)

#### Count users without comments

As @ClaytonC commented, the above answer does **not** include users without comments.

To fix this (if you actually need it), either LEFT JOIN to `users` right at the start after all:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT msg_ct, count(*) AS users
   FROM  (
      SELECT count(c.user_id) AS msg_ct
      FROM   users u
      LEFT   JOIN comments c ON c.user_id = u.id
      GROUP  BY u.id
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT ...
```

**Or**, since the join is just for finding users without comments, we *might* get away cheaper: Count *all* users and subtract users with comments (which we processed anyway):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT msg_ct, count(*)::int AS users
   FROM  (
      SELECT count(*)::int AS msg_ct
      FROM   comments 
      GROUP  BY user_id
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
, agg AS (
   SELECT max(msg_ct)   AS max_ct      -- maximum for generate_series
         ,((SELECT count(*) FROM users) - sum(users))::int AS users
                                       -- quiet rest with 0 comments
   FROM cte
   )
SELECT 0 AS msg_ct, users FROM agg     -- users with 0 comments
UNION  ALL
SELECT msg_ct, COALESCE(users, 0)
FROM  (SELECT generate_series(1, max_ct) AS msg_ct FROM agg) g
LEFT   JOIN cte USING (msg_ct)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The query gets a bit more complex, but it might be faster for big tables. Not sure. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (I would be grateful for a comment with the results.)

Comment: Great answer, as always! Thank you!